# Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to implement Authenticate with Firebase on Android using a Phone Number by following the [Google official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?authuser=0) on Xamarin Android. But I am getting this error:

`Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(java.lang.String, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit, com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider$OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks, android.app.Activity, java.util.concurrent.Executor, boolean)' on a null object reference'`

I created an Android studio project And I got no error sending sms. I was supposed to publish the app yesterday but I'm stuck here.

**Note**: I have already a reference to `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base`, `Xamarin.Firebase.Auth:71.1605.0` and I have a code with push notification `FCM` which is working fine.

Here is my `MainActivity.OnCreate` code:

```
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);

        var firebaseAuthInstance = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(firebaseApp);

        if(firebaseAuthInstance == null)
        {
            firebaseAuthInstance = new FirebaseAuth(firebaseApp);
        }

        verificationStateChangedCallbacks = new VerificationStateChangedCallbacks(); //This class is below.

        PhoneAuthProvider.Instance.VerifyPhoneNumber("+16505559999", 60, TimeUnit.Seconds, this //The activity, verificationStateChangedCallbacks); // I got the error here
```

Class `VerificationStateChangedCallbacks`:

```
public class VerificationStateChangedCallbacks : OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    {
        public override void OnVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential p0)
        {
        }

        public override void OnVerificationFailed(FirebaseException p0)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCodeSent(string p0, ForceResendingToken p1)
        {
            base.OnCodeSent(p0, p1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed it by changing

**PhoneAuthProvider.Instance**`.VerifyPhoneNumber("+16505559999", 60, TimeUnit.Seconds, this, verificationStateChangedCallbacks);`

to

**PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(firebaseAuthInstance)**`.VerifyPhoneNumber("+16505559999", 60, TimeUnit.Seconds, this, verificationStateChangedCallbacks);`

2 days and I didn't think about changing it.

Answer (score 0):

can you check whether "PhoneAuthProvider.Instance" a null object. If yes then please check your file "google-services.json". Normally "FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(firebaseApp)" will not return a null.

Comment: I have already a `google-services.json`  set as `GoogleServicesJson` buildAction using the same Firebase project. That's why I have no problem with the `FCM` service.  But I have overlay in debug mode the `PhoneAuthProvider.Instance` and it is not null. But by the way I just change it to `PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(firebaseAuthInstance)` and it is working right now.